# most or almost for this phrase

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

1. Most honey sold in the market is mixed/diluted with sugar.
2. Almost all honey sold in the markets is mixed/diluted with sugar.

Which one should be used to express the large amount of honey (up to 90%)?

- the observation found only 10% that can be classified as *pure honey*.

Answer (score 1):

*Most* and *almost all* are imprecise terms designating approximate ranges; but the two terms designate very ***different*** approximate ranges.

- Technically you can get away with using *most* for any portion greater than 50%, but in ordinary practice it is misleading to use *most* unless the portion is ***substantially*** greater than half. I'd feel uncomfortable using *most* for anything less than two-thirds of the total.
- *Almost all* is generally understood to designate a portion so large that the marginal quantity can and should be ignored. 90% is marginal; many people might regard that as legitimately *almost all*, but I personally would feel uncomfortable using *almost all* for anything less than 95%.